# Banjo maintenance

Tags: maintenance

I have a 17 inch 4 string tenor banjo. It is about a 80 year old Beacon (28058 model). It has an animal skin membrane. How do I know how tight the membrane should be?

Comment: Probably not an option right now, but by taking it to an expert or a music shop. It's impossible to tell without having it in front to see, feel and hear. Probably more important is to have it tuned so theat the tension is equal all round. 17 inch sounds a little strange. Please elaborate. Beacon banjos been around ony since the 60s, maybe it's a Bacon?

Comment: I thought the golden rule for banjos was to tighten it evenly until the skin breaks, then realise you should probably have backed it all off a quarter turn ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - Question - why do they put tuning pegs on banjos? No, I don't know either...

Comment: Banjo player meets a violist coming home from a gig… sorry, no, that can't be right...

Comment: The least used phrase in the English language: “There goes that banjo player in his Ferrari again...”

Comment: Perfect pitch: tossing an accordion into a dumpster and hitting a banjo.